# How to create an application in BullHorn Staffing Crm

Tags: api, rest

I try to get rest session token using rest api.But still now,I did not find where I create an application in bullhorn staffing crm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to create an application using Bullhorn CRM.
Iniially request the client id & client secret from Bullhorn by raising a ticket.

**Steps** to begin with Bullhorn CRM:

1) Get the 'authorization code' using the following URL:

**auth9.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&username={username}&password={password}&action=Login**

The 'authorization code' will be available in the redirected url within parameter 'code'.

2) Use this 'authorization code' to get the 'access token' & 'refresh token' using URL:

**auth9.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code={authorization code}&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}**

Here a JSON is returned with 'access token' & 'refresh token'.

3) Use the above 'access token' & 'refresh token' to get 'BhRestToken'(also called session key)  and 'RestUrl' which will be used in subsequent API calls, using URL:

**rest9.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-services/login?version=*&access_token={access_token}**

It returns a JSON response comprising 'BhRestToken' and 'RestUrl'.

For further assistance you may also consult http://developer.bullhorn.com/articles/getting_started

Comment: Thank you ,Your answer is useful.I tried to raise a ticket through Support->BullHorn Resource Center but it shows a error "Login Error : Please contact your administrator or support contact".Any idea to raise a ticket?

Comment: You have two options for contacting Bullhorn:
1) Call them on:
US Support 617-478-9126
UK Support +44 800 032 2848 ext. 9131
Australia Support (02) 8006 1319
International Support +1 617 478 9131

or Second, you can open a ticket via the Bullhorn Resource Center. To complete this action, you would open the Support menu in Bullhorn and click Bullhorn Resource Center. From there, you will see an option to open a Bullhorn Support Ticket.

Comment: @ashu1992 why is necessary to obtain a session key? How often those session key expired?